# list all columns with amount of different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get a table with two columns:

- one contains each column names of a table
- the second contains the count of different values that are stored in this column.

So if I have a table with four columns:

```
id boat fish    date
1  2    Brass   2014-08-03
2  3    Halibut 2014-08-03
3  2    Plaice  2014-08-04
4  1    Salmon  2014-08-04
5  3    Plaice  2014-08-04
```

the resulting table should be either

```
column count
id     5
boat   3
fish   4
date   2
```

or

```
id boat fish date
5  3    4    2
```

I tried:

```
SELECT c.name AS column_name, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [c.name]) FROM catches)
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE t.name LIKE '%catches%'
```

Which won't work because I can't use the string from `c.name` as a column identifier. At least not the way I tried. Can I, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, you can just use count distincts:

```
select
count (distinct [id]) as IDs,
count (distinct boat)  as boats,
count (distinct fish) as fish,
count (distinct [date]) as dates
       from
       table1
```

Which returns:

```
IDS     BOATS   FISH    DATES
5       3       4       2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/033bc/3)

EDIT:
Having re-read your question, if you have significant number of columns or you don't want to hard code the column names, you can use a cursor to build your select.  I suspect if you tried hard enough, you could build a pivot to do the same thing, but in this particular case, I think a cursor is an OK solution.
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

```
set @SQL = 'SELECT '
DECLARE @Counter integer
set @Counter = 0
declare @colName nvarchar(100)



DECLARE cols CURSOR 
for
select
distinct sc.name as ColName
from
sys.tables  st
inner join sys.schemas ss
    on st.schema_id = st.schema_id
inner join sys.columns sc
    on st.object_id = sc.object_id
where
st.name = '<YourTable>'  
and ss.name = '<YourSchema>'

open cols
fetch next from cols into @colName


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
begin
    if (@counter = 0) 
        begin
            set @SQL = @SQL + 'COUNT(DISTINCT ' +@colName + ') AS ' + @colName + 's'
        end
    else
        begin
            set @SQL = @SQL + ',COUNT(DISTINCT ' +@colName + ') AS ' + @colName + 's'
        end
    set @Counter = @Counter + 1
    fetch next from cols into @colName
end

close cols
deallocate cols
set @SQL = @SQL + ' from <YourSchema>.<YourTable>'
print @SQL
EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
begin
    if (@counter = 0) 
        begin
            set @SQL = @SQL + 'COUNT(DISTINCT ' +@colName + ') AS ' + @colName + 's'
        end
    else
        begin
            set @SQL = @SQL + ',COUNT(DISTINCT ' +@colName + ') AS ' + @colName + 's'
        end
    set @Counter = @Counter + 1
    fetch next from cols into @colName
end

close cols
deallocate cols
set @SQL = @SQL + ' from Auditing.T_RPT_DIM'
print @SQL
EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL
```